# Wildfly 8.0 + RichFaces 4.2.2 + IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea, jboss, richfaces

I'm making working on a project and I need to use JBoss server (Wildfly) with JSF+RichFaces.
I am able to run normal JSF, but when I add some RichFaces components it doesn't show up on the webpage (only the RichFaces component doesn't show!)
I am also getting this warning:

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://richfaces.org/rich
>   declared with prefix rich but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

Do I need to maybe change faces-config.xml or web.xml because I didn't touch these 2 files, used the default generated by IntelliJ IDEA.

Here is my JSF file:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:body>
    <h3>Followers:</h3>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectOneListbox value="#{helloBean.user}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.users}" />
        </h:selectOneListbox>
    </h:form>

    <h3>Following:</h3>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="users" value="#{helloBean.user}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.users}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton value="Unfollow">
            <f:ajax execute="users" render="output" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>
    </h:form>

    <h3>Users:</h3>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="cols,cols" width="400">
            <rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" itemMode="ajax" groupMode="ajax" groupExpandedLeftIcon="triangleUp"
                            groupCollapsedLeftIcon="triangleDown" topGroupExpandedRightIcon="chevronUp"
                            topGroupCollapsedRightIcon="chevronDown" itemLeftIcon="disc" itemChangeListener="#{panelMenuBean.updateCurrent}">
                <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 1">
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.1" name="Item_1_1" />
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.2" name="Item_1_2" />
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.3" name="Item_1_3" />
                </rich:panelMenuGroup>
                <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 2">
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.1" name="Item_2_1" />
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.2" name="Item_2_2" />
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.3" name="Item_2_3" />
                    <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 2.4">
                        <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.4.1" name="Item_2_4_1" />
                        <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.4.2" name="Item_2_4_2" />
                        <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.4.3" name="Item_2_4_3" />
                    </rich:panelMenuGroup>
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 2.5" name="Item_2_5" />
                </rich:panelMenuGroup>
                <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 3">
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 3.1" name="Item_3_1" />
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 3.2" name="Item_3_2" />
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 3.3" name="Item_3_3" />
                </rich:panelMenuGroup>
            </rich:panelMenu>
            <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                <rich:panel rendered="#{not empty panelMenuBean.current}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{panelMenuBean.current} selected" id="current" />
                </rich:panel>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the richfaces libaries is included in the classpath of your application? Is the project Maven based? Maybe you are missing the dependency.

Comment: The project isn't Maven based, and I don't think Im missing richfaces libraries, there are in the lib folder.

Comment: You don't need to pimp the web.xml or faces-config.xml to get especially for RichFaces. Why don't you try using one of the provided samples from the current release: http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/stable.html.

Comment: You don't need change web.xml or faces-config.xml (as Spindizzy said), but you need add RichFaces jars in export to war (it can be part of build process, or simple check in "Order and Export" tab of project's "Java Build Path").

Comment: When I add RichFaces jars I'm getting this errors while compiling: [2014-06-30 12:32:33,257] Artifact RichTest3:ejb exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2014-06-30 12:32:33,257] Artifact RichTest3:ejb exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"RichTest3_ejb_exploded.rar\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"RichTest3_ejb_exploded.rar\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"RichTest3_ejb_exploded.rar\""}}

Answer (score 0):

WildFly is packed with JSF 2.2.x implementation based on Mojarra.
Rich faces 4.5 can provides support for JSF 2.2

Rich faces 4.5.0 Final is released recently. Details are available at [4.5.0 Final](http://www.bleathem.ca//blog/2014/10/richfaces-450final-release-announcement.html)

You need to upgrade to Rich faces 4.5